# Is it possible to set up a proxy for a remote desktop connection

Tags: rdp

One of my clients needs me to access their server using a Windows Remote Desktop connection. The trouble I have is that they are insisting on restricting access at the firewall to a single source IP address. My office ISP keep changing my IP address and it is becoming a nuisance getting the firewall updated each time.

I have a number of servers not doing much in a remote server farm. All of these do have a fixed IP address. Is there something I could install/setup on my servers that would allow me to have them reflect the RDP connection from my office PC to my Clients server?

Answer (score 2):

Use [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on servers with fixed IP. Use need froward 3389 TCP Port. Or use VPN on servers with fixed IP([OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any proxy software for RDP, but what should be possible is to setup a VPN (PPTP, IPSEC etc) to one of the remote servers and NAT the connection behind the server's ip address. This will make the connection appear to come from the server's ip and it should be a lot easier to keep the VPN up to date.

If one of the remote servers runs a favor of Linux/BSD with OpenSSH, you could also use Putty to tunnel. In Putty, before connecting go to "Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels". Under the "Add new forwarded port" section, but the source port as 66389, and the destination as $rdpip:3389 and hit "Add". Then open the connection as normal. Then tell remote desktop to connect to localhost:63389 and it use the tunnel and will appear to come from the ssh server's ip address.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to muck around with VPNs, tunnels, etc, just install a generic TCP proxy on your server computers with the static IP addresses. Something like [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) would work fine.

Comment: That looks promising to solve a similar problem for me, although I always have some reservations about using software not updated for 8 years.

Comment: What rinetd does is dirt simple and hasn't expanded in scope over the years. I wouldn't see its lack of updates as being anything more than an indication that it does the simple job it was designed for well and hasn't had any major bugs detected.